# ionic push tutorial error

Tags: java, android, push-notification, ionic-framework

While go through the Push From Scratch tutorial I'm getting error on android:

```
'663716   error    $ionicPush:REGISTER_ERROR, java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String'
```

Can anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: It means that you need to convert your long to String (probably register id?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, that `gcm_id` should be passed as string. Closing.